# Appending values to empty dataframe returns NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to append all shop dates to a new dataframe.
But when I append it all values is NaN
Im sure that sd has values, I've printed it and it was plenty. :)

```py
cg = vn[vn['name'] == n]
data = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=cg.columns,index=cg.index)

for date in cg['date'].unique():
    sd = cg[(cg['date'] == date)]
    data.append(sd, ignore_index=True)

print(data)
```

Comment: in your for loop just do data = data.append(sd,ignore_index = True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.append` doesn't not do what `List.append` does, it more closely resembles `List + item` in behavior.

It doesn't change your object but instead returns a new object with the item appended

[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is the documentation for this

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```py
data = data.append(sd, ignore_index=True)
```

`append` returns a dataframe, it's not in-place.